# Setting an MP3s as podcasts in iTunes

Tags: itunes, music, podcasts, mp3

I have an iPod Nano 3rd Generation that I use to listen both music and podcasts from iTunes.

Now the issue: I have a bunch of non-iTunes podcasts in MP3 format that I want to add to my iPod as podcasts.

So far, if I add them, they get added as music and they get mixed with the music and I don't like this solution because if I shuffle I get podcasts mixed with my music.

There is any way to keep those MP3 podcasts separated from my MP3 music? Is there a way to keep them with the iTunes podcasts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue has little to do with an iPod Nano but has to do with MP3 settings for the MP3 file itself in iTunes. To change a plain MP3 to a podcast, open up iTunes, select the MP3 then select `Get Info` on the MP3, select `Options` & then look at the `Media Kind` list. One of the `Media Kind` options is `Podcast` so just select that and then copy the newly modified MP3 file to your iPod Nano or any iDevice. You should be good to go.

[image]

Comment: I'm on Windows iTunes 12.5.5.5.  This method works, but the "converted" podcast does not show up in iTunes under Podcasts, only on my device in the Podcasts app.

Comment: How do I do it in Music.app since iTunes is no more as of 2021?